# How to render pages those are related to user roles in angular

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

First of all I am very new in Angular JS. I am working in a project, where I have three types of users and all three users have different kind of views. Now My question is, can it be possible after login, render only pages/views those are belong to logged in user instead of all pages? If yes then how?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Are you talking about only showing certain views on a page?  That could be accomplished with `ng-show` or `ng-visible`.  You need to let javascript know about your roles somehow, and you could create your own directive that removes elements if the user isn't in a certain role for instance...

Comment: @JasonGoemaat: First of all thanks for replying. I have three users:admin,investor,founder. All three have different views.Will it be possible to load pages/views those are belong to loggedin user?

Comment: You probably want to look at writing an angular service to handle authentication and authorization for your project. This can be done in many ways, you can find an example implementation here: https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth  .

Comment: I would do something like that on the server side, probably redirect them to a completely different url (i.e. `/admin`, `/investor` or `/founder`.  Even if you had to return different html with the same url, I would do that on the server side.  I can't picture what you're trying to do exactly or why you would want the views only to be different.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it on the server side. Something like this. This will enject the right angular app based on what kind of user flag is set. Of course this would mean that you had a flag on each user that indicates what type of user they are. You could just use a unique attribute of the type of user and it would work the same. This will allow unique views, and controllers for each different kind of user. I'm assuming you want one url to serve up three different types of angular app based on what the user is. If you want to control what URLs are accessible, that's something else entirely and should be handled in your django views.

```
{% if user.is_staff %}
    <div ng-app='staffApp'>
{% elif user.is_investor %}
    <div ng-app='investorApp'>
{% elif user.is_founder %}
    <div ng-app="founder">
{% endif %}
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another way is just have an attirbute that each user has like

```
@property
def ng-app(self):
    return 'investorApp'
```

And then in your template do

```
<div ng-app='{{ user.ng-app }}'>
     <div ng-view>
     </div>
</div>
```

But any way, I think this would be the correct way to solve your question :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am running completely independent angular front side app. there is no django templating.